# Excel If statement to check if cell contains certain characters and copy them to other cells

Tags: excel

I'm looking for an If statement that will copy text from one cell to another

Its being a long time since I did any if statements in excel and am not sure if this can be done

Its for work purposes to save time, not school or college or anything

Basically what im looking for is an if statement that will check for specific characters in the project worked column and copy them to there respective columns on the right

For instance if(cell d contains "TN", put TN in column K)

[image]

Comment: I'm writing them manually into each cell based on project worked column and its very time consuming

Comment: What have you found and tried? This is not an uncommon sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in F3:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&F$2&",",","&SUBSTITUTE($D3," ","")&",")),F$2,"")
```

Copy over and down

[image]

Comment: seems to work now if I put it in at very top, thank you very much

Comment: Yes if you do not start on row 3 then you need to adjust to your starting row.

Comment: Appreciate the help mate, this will save a lot of time,

is there anyway to refine this a little more, I have 2 similar entries BL and BLST

where only BLST exists it is also adding an entry into the BL column